# How to dynamically add/remove slot fields, based on an array in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following, which takes a slot containing the HTML fields to be repeated:

```
<div  v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="index">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between ">
        <slot name="fields">
        </slot>
        <input  v-model="row.value" />
        <button @click="removeRow(index)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-float waves-light height-10-per  " >
          Remove <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When I use `removeRow(index)`, it always removes the last slot. I've tested with using the `<input v-model="row.value">` and the correct input is removed here, but never the correct slot.

I do not need the inputs in the slot to be dynamic or interact with Vue, I simply want to allow the user to add new rows/remove rows dynamically via a Vue component.

Please see the below two methods I've used for adding/removing rows, in case an issue lies here:

```
    removeRow(index){
      this.rows.splice(index, 1);
    },
    addRow(){
      this.rows.push({value: 'test'})
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a unique `key` value to your `v-for` loop element:

```
<div-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="JSON.stringify(row)">
```

This should make sure the correct element is removed from the DOM.

Comment: I did have that on there, but removed it when troubleshooting, having the key on there doesn't fix it and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Madmunster Sorry, updated the question. The index would be replaced which would be problematic anyway. Instead, I've chosen to `JSON.stringify` the `row` for more uniqueness.

Comment: I did that and then I've also updated the value that gets pushed to always be unique, that's resolved it - thank you!